# Automapper - projectTo() - Aggregation on base entity (DbSet)

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper

I'm trying to aggregate multiple filters against my base entity when using the projectTo() method.

However if I define a `IQueryable<TSource>` to `<TDestination>` profile, automapper is always trying to map between `<TSource>` and `<TDestination>`. And so the mapping profile is not found.

I see in the [docs](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html#aggregations) it is possible to aggregate against a member list.

Is this possible with Automapper?

DbEntity (Source)

```
public SomeClass {
  Member1: bool
  Member2: bool
}
```

Destination

```
public DestinationClass {
  TotalSomeClass: int;
  TotalSomeClassWithMember1True: int;
}
```

Mapping Profile (Not working)

```
CreateMap<IQueryable<SomeClass>, DestinationClass >()
        .ForMember(d => d.TotalSomeClass, o
            => o.MapFrom(s => s.Count()))
        .ForMember(d => d.TotalSomeClassWithMember1True, o
            => o.MapFrom(s => s.Count(s => s.Member1 == true)))
```

Usage (Automapper 11 with dependency injection)

```
var result = _mapper.ProjectTo<DestinationClass>(_context.SomeClass);
```

Comment: What error do you get when you run your code?

Comment: Missing map from Pro.ject.Models.SomeClass to Pro.ject..REST.Response.DestinationClass . Create using CreateMap<SomeClass , DestinationClass >."

Comment: I'm not sure, but  you might be using `.ProjectTo()` wrong -- try something like `_context.SomeClass.ProjectTo<DestinationClass>();` instead and see what happens. Refer to https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html for more info.

Comment: As per https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Dependency-injection.html#queryable-extensions, "_context.SomeClass.ProjectTo<DestinationClass>()" would be considered the "old syntax"  IMapper.ProjectTo is the new... My usage may still be wrong?

Comment: I tested the old syntax now using _contex.SomeClass.ProjectTo<DestinationClass>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider); .. Same result.  Also how could you, asuming this is possible call the result into memory?   .firstOrDefualtAsync() ? If this mapping worked we are going from a collection to one object

Comment: I also tested the basic _mapper.Map<DestinationClass>(_contex.SomeClass), this works confirming my mapping profile and config. But the behavior isn't the same as projectTo() would be? I.e. Each count() in the mapping is executed as a standalone query in EF